# not showing the option of build apk in build < flutter < build apk

Tags: flutter, flutter-apk

[image: build]

not showing the option of build apk in build < flutter < build apk , other project showing the option of build apk

Comment: Have you installed plugins of dart and flutter in android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

That option is available when you open the `android` module in Android Studio.

Click on

```
Tools > Flutter > Open for Editing in Android Studio
```

[image]

Now you've the option:

[image]

Comment: its also not showing the flutter option in tools

Comment: task & contexts,generate javacode,ide scripiting console,xml actions,jshell console,groovy console,kotlin

Comment: Ok, search `build.gradle` file and open it. After opening the file, does it show something like `Open module in Android Studio` at the top right corner?

Comment: Ok, then you can directly open the `android` folder from your project directory in Android Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227523/discussion-between-fawad-ahmed-and-copsonroad).